# Why does html constructed within play 2 scala templates produce a empty Html case class

Tags: templates, scala, pattern-matching, playframework-2.0

Why does this output "html is empty"?

```
@h = {<br />}

@h match {
  case Html("") => {html is empty}
  case _ => {html has content}
}
```

and this outputs "html has content"?

```
@i = @{Html("<br />")}

@i match {
  case Html("") => {html is empty}
  case _ => {html has content}
}
```

The reason this matters to me is because in the [common use cases](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaTemplateUseCases) last example (moreScripts and moreStyles equivalents), the first style is used to pass in a chuck of html into another template. I then want to switch based on if that html has content or not. But it always matches to Html("").

Comment: What happens when you output `@h` - empty String?

Comment: Both @h and @i output a <br />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code generated for each of the methods is slightly different.

```
def h:play.api.templates.Html = {
  _display_(
    Seq[Any](format.raw("""<br />"""))
  )
}
def i = {{Html("<br />")}}
```

The `_display_` method used in creating `h` ends up performing a `foldLeft` on all the elements of the passed in `Seq`

This results in:

```
Html("") + Html("<br />")
```

The `Html` case class turns out to be backed by a mutable `StringBuilder`.

```
case class Html(text: String) extends Appendable[Html] with Content with play.mvc.Content {
  val buffer = new StringBuilder(text)

  /**
   * Appends this HTML fragment to another.
   */
  def +(other: Html): Html = {
    buffer.append(other.buffer)
    this
  }
  override def toString = buffer.toString

  /**
   * Content type of HTML (`text/html`).
   */
  def contentType: String = "text/html"

  def body: String = toString

}
```

This means that the value of `text` is only ever going to be set to the value of the first `Html`'s `text` value. Whenever you create a new `Html` via the `+` method you only modify the `StringBuilder`.

E.g.

```
val html = Html("1") + Html("2")
html.text == "1"
html.toString == "12"
html.body == "12"
```

Since it is the `text` value that is used for pattern matching this effectively breaks its ability to be used in pattern matching.

E.g.

```
(Html("1") + Html("2")) match { case Html("1") => "broken" } // returns "broken"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing a string match?

```
@h.toString() match {
  case "" => {html is empty}
  case _ => {html has content}
}
```

Comment: That fails to compile, and also kind of defeats to purpose of pattern matching. I am wondering why two forms of assignment result in only one being able to be pattern matched on.